# *ngFor not updating in child component after modify object

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

I am using below code to bind data using *ngFor. 
--***Child Component "my-productDetails***".

```
import { Component, Input, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
@Component({

    selector: 'my-productDetails',
    styleUrls: ['styles.css'],
    template: `

                     <h5>Product Details</h5> <br><br>
<div class="fontStyle1">
                  <table>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Name</th>  <th>Price</th>  <th>Store Name</th>  <th>Model</th> 
                        </tr>

                        <tr  *ngFor="let obj of ProductDetails">
                           <td>{{obj.name}}</td>
                           <td>{{obj.price | currency:'USD':true }}</td>
                           <td>{{obj.store}}</td>
                           <td> {{obj.model}}</td>
                        </tr>
                   </table>
</div>
               `,
})

export class ProductDetailsComponent {

    public ProductDetails = [
    { name: 'Hp Laptop', price: '500', store: 'Best Buy', model: '15-BS013DX' },
    { name: 'Dell Laptop', price: '700', store: 'Amazon', model: 'I7378-3000SLV-PUS' },
    { name: 'Lenovo Laptop', price: '670', store: 'Target', model: '81A40025US' } ];

    constructor() {
        console.log("getProducts constructor");
        this.getProducts();
    }
    getProducts() {
        console.log("getProducts");

            return this.ProductDetails;
        }
```

***Parent Component:***

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductDetailsComponent } from './app.productDetails.component';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-productHeader',
    template: `
                <div>
                       <h5>Product Header</h5>
                </div>
                <div>
                        Select Product <select>
                                            <option *ngFor="let prod of ProductList" value={{prod.model}}>
                                                                    {{prod.name  }}
                                            </option>

                                       </select>
                </div>
<div>
<button type="text" (click)="searchProduct('Hp Laptop')">Search</button>
</div>

                <div>
                         <my-productDetails></my-productDetails>
                </div>
`,
})

export class ProductHeader {

    public ProductList: Object = {};
    public order: string = 'name';
    constructor() {

        let prodlist: ProductDetailsComponent = new ProductDetailsComponent();
        this.ProductList = prodlist.getProducts();
        console.log(this.ProductList[0].name);
    console.log("Product Header 2");
}

    searchProduct(Name: string) {
        let prodlist: ProductDetailsComponent = new ProductDetailsComponent();
         prodlist.SearchProduct(Name);
    }
}
```

In First load data was binding successfully.
[image]

I have search functionality on button click. I want to bind data to a table based on product search. Why table is not updating on second time. It shows all items.

```
SearchProduct(name: string) {
    console.log(name);
    let obj = this.ProductDetails.filter(m => m.name == 'Dell Laptop');
    this.ProductDetails = obj;
    console.log(this.ProductDetails);// I can see in log Dell Product, that means search method is working fine, only view is not updating .

}
```

And also i checked my search code is returning expected row. I am using this component with another component like a child component.

My question is **How to update a child component on Click Button Search?**

Comment: Nothing wrong. Code works in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-axsdvd?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: If you have `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` in your component, try removing that line.

Comment: I forgot to add one more Point, ProductDetails was a child component.

Comment: Your child selector  <my-productDetails></my-productDetails>  should have inputs , outputs and emitters

 <my-productDetails [prod-details]="ProductDetails"></my-productDetails>

Currently its tied up to a stand alone instance and not to the instance of "ProdtDetails" of the parent "ProductHeader".

Read this for how to create input and output
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1207339/Learn-Angular-Tutorial-Part#Lab_10_Input,_Output_and_emitters